# Проверка что дата меньше 60 дней

Tags: java

Необходимо проверить что до конца даты активации осталось меньше 60 дней. Но не пойму как сделать чтоб если дата меньше двух месяцев, то делаем это, а если больше то это.

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

 long timeUp = format.parse(DateActivation).getTime();
 long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeUp;
 long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

 System.out.println(DateActivation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String inputString1 = "2020-04-13 00:00:00";
String inputString2 = "2020-01-13 00:00:00";

Date date1 = format.parse(inputString1);
Date date2 = format.parse(inputString2);
long diff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
long days = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

System.out.println("Days: " + days);
if (days >= 60) {
    System.out.println("Прошло 60 или больше дней");
} else {
    System.out.println("Прошло меньше 60 дней");
}
```

**UPD.**

Если сравнивать текущую дату с заданной:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String inputString = "2020-01-13 00:00:00";

Date date = format.parse(inputString);
long diff = Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis() - date.getTime());
long days = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

System.out.println("Days: " + days);
if (days >= 60) {
    System.out.println("Прошло 60 или больше дней");
} else {
    System.out.println("Прошло меньше 60 дней");
}
```

Comment: Увы это не работает, хотя я прекрасно понимаю что должно.

Comment: @НиколайГнап, т.е. вы запустили мой код и он у вас не написал `Прошло 60 или больше дней`? О_о

Comment: Все нормально пародонте )))

Comment: @НиколайГнап, бывает, но на всякий, во избежания недоразумений, добавил в ответ пример сравнения с текущей датой :)

Comment: Извините только сейчас заметил что вопрос мой был отредактирован и не верно трактован модератором. Мне необходимо проверить    что до конца даты активации осталось меньше 60 дней, и активировать заново. Но также активировать если прошло больше 360 дней.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `java.time.Period`.

Правда, точность будет до дней, а часы, минуты и секунды придется отбросить:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDate activationDate = LocalDate.parse("2020-02-13 22:12:34", dtf);

System.out.println(Period.between(activationDate, LocalDate.now()).getMonths()); //2
```